# About the mongodb's default db path?

Tags: mongodb

Environment:

- 3.4.9-gentoo
- mongodb (OpenRC) 0.9.8.4 (Gentoo Linux)

if I use `mongod` daemon to start mongodb，the default db path is `/data/db`

But if I use `/etc/init.d/mongodb` script to start mongodb, the `/etc/conf.d/mongdb` write the default db path is `/var/lib/mongodb`,

I am puzzled that why the db path is not the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default [dbpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#dbpath) if you start MongoDB without a configuration file is `/data/db`.

Your init script (`/etc/init.d/mongodb`) is starting mongodb with the `--config` (aka `-f`) option and a path to a config file to use (`/etc/conf.d/mongodb`).

If you look at the contents of your `/etc/config.mongodb` configuration file, you should see the `dbpath` setting with the `/var/lib/mongodb` directory path that overrides the default.  In this case the maintainer of your MongoDB install package has decided that `/var/lib` is the most appropriate default directory for data files.  Generally this is done to be more consistent with the default locations used by other packages in your distribution; the MongoDB data files can live anywhere on your filesystem.

You can also check for any settings that have been overridden by your configuration file in the `mongo` shell using:

```
 getCommandLineOpts()
```

The output will be similar to:

```
{
    "argv" : [
        "mongod",
        "--dbpath",
        "/var/lib/mongodb"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "dbpath" : "/var/lib/mongodb"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: the /etc/init.d/mongodb doesn't have --config/-f option in my environment:Options: [dDsvl:ZChqVv]

Comment: ok, I have read the doc you give; default(without conf), it will use /data/db, but `Typical location` suggest is `/var/lib/mongodb`